# Respect/validation: Mandatory keys inside a keySet, how can I get a missing key name in error messages?

Tags: php, respect-validation

I'm using [Respect/Validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation) and I created the following rules to validate and associative array:

```
Validator::keySet(
        Validator::key( // mandatory, if included type: string, values: not null, not empty
            'name',
            Validator::stringType()->notEmpty()
        ),
        Validator::key( // mandatory, if included type: string, values: not null, not empty
            'company',
            Validator::stringType()->notEmpty()
        ),
        Validator::key( // mandatory, if included type: string, values: not null, not empty
            'type',
            Validator::stringType()->notEmpty()
        ),
        Validator::key( // mandatory, if included type: string, values: not null, not empty
            'country',
            Validator::stringType()->notEmpty()
        ),
        Validator::key( // optional, if included type: string, values: not null, not empty
            'comment',
            Validator::stringType()->notEmpty(),
            false
        )
    );
```

and when I validate an array, it works fine but if some of mandatory keys are missing (let's say "company" key) I always get an error message like:

`- Must have keys { "name", "company", "type", "country", "comment" }`

But I would like to customize the error messages and get something like:

`"company" field is missing`

I've tried:

```
$errors = $exception->findMessages([
...
'keyset' => '{{name}} field is missing',
....
]);
```

but `{{name}}` includes the whole array with key and values...

Is there any way to get that customize error message? should I include another `{{placeholder}}`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try some of the followings:

```
Validator::key( // mandatory, if included type: string, values: not null, not empty
        'company',
        Validator::stringType()->notEmpty()->setName('company')
    ),
```

Or

```
Validator::key( // mandatory, if included type: string, values: not null, not empty
        'company',
        Validator::stringType()->notEmpty()->setName('company')->setTemplate('"{{name}}" field is missing')
    ),
```

https://respect-validation.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/feature-guide/#validator-name

> Validator name
>
> On v::attribute() and v::key(), {{name}} is the attribute/key name. For others, is the same as the input. You can customize a validator name using:
>
> ```
> v::date('Y-m-d')->between('1980-02-02', 'now')->setName('Member Since');
> ```

https://respect-validation.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/feature-guide/#exception-types

> Exception types
>
> ```
> Respect\Validation\Exceptions\ExceptionInterface:
>     All exceptions implement this interface;
> Respect\Validation\Exceptions\ValidationException:
>     Implements the Respect\Validation\Exceptions\ExceptionInterface interface
>     Thrown when the check() fails
>     All validation exceptions extend this class
>     Available methods:
>         getMainMessage();
>         setMode($mode);
>         setName($name);
>         setParam($name, $value);
>         setTemplate($template);
>         more...
> Respect\Validation\Exceptions\NestedValidationException:
>     Extends the Respect\Validation\Exceptions\ValidationException class
>     Usually thrown when the assert() fails
>     Available methods:
>         findMessages();
>         getFullMessage();
>         getMessages();
>         more...
> ```